# Intersection of principal filters

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Prove that intersection of principal filters on $I$ is still a principal filter.

Let S be a nonempty set and C be a nonempty subset. Then {C} is a filter base. The filter it generates (i.e., the collection of all subsets containing C) is called the principal filter generated by C. Sorry for posting in this way, I understand it's not polite, but could you give any tip-off.

Comment: What is $I$? What is the definition of a principal filter (on $I$)? What have you tried?

Comment: _I_ is an arbitrary set. Actually I was asked to post it here for any ideas.

Comment: That answers one of my questions. What about the other two? It isn't a problem to post such things here, and people will be glad to help you, but we'll be able to give you a better answer if we know more about what you've done, what your definitions are, etc.

Comment: Let S be a nonempty set and C be a nonempty subset. Then {C} is a filter base. The filter it generates (i.e., the collection of all subsets containing C) is called the principal filter generated by C. Sorry for posting in this way, I understand it's not polite, but could you give any tip-off.

Comment: @Minimus: Using *principle* is widespread e.g. for filters and bundles, but it's [simply wrong](http://grammarist.com/spelling/principle-principal/).

Comment: @kushtibargo: Please [edit] the question to include what you have said in comments; that way, people won't have to plough through them to make a proper assessment of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preliminary definitions:

“D is a filter” = df.
i.D $\subseteq$S(I) for some nonempty set I, where S(I) is the powerset of I, &
ii. I$\in$D;
iii. Given X, Y$\in$D, then X$\cap$Y $\in$D;
iv. Given X $\in$ D & X$\subseteq$Z $\subseteq$I then Z$\subseteq$ D.

“D is principal” =df.  D is a filter and D = {X$\subseteq$I:Y $\subseteq$ X}.

1. Prove: D is principal iff $\cap$D$\in$D.

Left to Right of “iff”: Suppose that D is a principal filter. Then D = {X$\subseteq$I: Y$\subseteq$ X}. So take $\cap$D. Clearly $\cap$D = Y, and Y $\in$ D (Y$\subseteq$ Y, and Y is thus one of the subsets of I having Y as subset). Thus $\cap$D$\in$D.  <END OF LEFT TO RIGHT>.

Right to Left of “iff”: Suppose that $\cap$D$\in$D, and that D is a filter. We show D is principal. Thus by assumption D $\subseteq$ S(I), and so $\cap$ D$\in$S(I) hence $\cap$ D$ $ $\subset$ I. Thus $\exists$Y: D$\subseteq$Y & Y$\subseteq$I. Now call {Y: D $\subseteq$ Y & Y $\subseteq$ I} = Z. Clearly $\cap$D $\in$ Z. But $\cap$D $\in$ D as well (by initial assumption); so by extensionality D = Z; and so we have the appropriate D, so that D must be principal. <END OF RIGHT TO LEFT>.

<END OF PROOF>.

Comment: Please write the content of your answer here, not on any external website. [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: @ لويس العرب I am sorry but what is $Y$ in the $D=\{X\subseteq I: Y\subseteq X\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Take any two non-empty subsets $A,B$ of $I$, and let $\mathcal E,\mathcal F$ the principal filters on $I$ that they generate. Then $\mathcal E\cap\mathcal F$ is the set of subsets $C$ of $I$ that contain both $A$ and $B$ (that is, having both $A$ and $B$ as subsets). If $C\subseteq I$ is such that $A,B\subseteq C,$ what can you say with regard to $A\cup B$ and $C$? If $A\cup B\subseteq C,$ what can you say with regard to $A,B$ and $C$?

Comment: _M={A, B}_, so _M_ generates filter with base _A_ and _B_?

Comment: That has $A$ and $B$ as **elements**. When we say that a set $S$ "contains" a set $T$, we mean that $T\subseteq S.$

Comment: @kushtibargo: Suppose that $A\subseteq S$ and $B\subseteq S$; what can you say about $A\cup B$?